# Visual Studio 2013 stopped working after removing dlls from GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, gac, gacutil

After removing some dlls from the GAC using `gacutil -u <dll>` in the Visual Studio 2013 command line, my Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working.

When I open it, it crashes with the following error in event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x54548724  
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18444, time stamp: 0x52717e84  
Exception code: 0xc00000fd  
Fault offset: 0x0000451a  
Faulting process id: 0x16ac  
Faulting application start time: 0x01d055e5a2af5c16  
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe  
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll  
Report Id: e06ef1f8-c1d8-11e4-93eb-547ae8ae8114
```

Comment: You crashed VS with this site's name, 0xc00000fd is the exception code for a stack overflow exception.  That's a rather fatal mishap, they didn't pick this site's name for frivolous stuff.  Any kind of "you probably should not have done that" advice is rather obvious, the least-tested code is the code that doesn't expect the world to collapse.  Keep in mind that you can pretty easily crash VS with your own code, an SOE at design-time in Winforms is just as bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. In my case help me -> Run cmd -> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE -> devenv.exe /rootsuffix Test